# Where to get Xamarin libraries from in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

So I just created a brand new xamarin soultion through the visual studio IDE. The first thing I do is press build and I see various libaries cannot be found for example - 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' could not be found.

What is the best way to go about getting these references. I did a search for Xamarin in Nuget that came up with no results.

Xamarin Libraries can be found by right clicking on components, add new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Xamarin.Forms on Nuget http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/